# extract simultaneous data from 2 columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have a table made of 2 columns `message_id`, `message_id_reply` what I need:

1. to extract this id that is equal with external php variable
2. to extract every id from the row above if it exists in the `message_id_reply` column

Here's my table:

```
+------------+------------------+
| message_id | message_id_reply |
+------------+------------------+
|         75 |               70 |
|         76 |               75 |
|         77 |               76 |
|         78 |               77 |
|         80 |               79 |
|         81 |               80 |
|         82 |               81 |
|         83 |               74 |
|         84 |               79 |
|         85 |               70 |
|         86 |               84 |
|         88 |               73 |
|         89 |               88 |
+------------+------------------+
```

EX1:If I send `message_id = 78` I need to get `78,77,76,75,70`.

EX2:If I send `message_id = 86` I need to get `86,84,79`.

EX3:If I send `message_id = 90` I need to get `90,78,77,76,75,70`.

Comment: if u pass 32, then it should take 32, 31, 30 ?

Comment: you need a recursive query right? mysql doesn't natively support it, but with php it is possible

Comment: perhaps it is recursive query, i just need to check is message_id is equal with message_id_reply from next row, this way to get the all conversation from the start.

Comment: I would suggest to change your data structure, and associate each message to a `conversation_id` so you can query them all faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `message_id` <= '$id'";
```

Comment: Downvote for SQL injection vulnerabilities in answer

Comment: true sorry, but lets say from where ever he gets the id, he did not specify from where he is getting the id. Anyway sorry.

Comment: Yes, but if I have :
+------------+------------------+
| message_id | message_id_reply |
+------------+------------------+
|         75 |               70 |
|         76 |               75 |
|         77 |               76 |
|         78 |               77 |
|         80 |               79 |
|         81 |               80 |
+------------+------------------+
and I want to select message_id = 81 I need to get the answer 81,80,79.
Because the 78,77,76,75,70 is from other tree.

Comment: @Serghei - please **edit your question** to include this valuable clarification